# swift: Set custom image to each section in UITable View

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to set the image to sections in UITable View. but as soon as i add the image the Title from the section disappears.
 This is what i have tried:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return "Exam"
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        return "Lab"
    }
    else if(section == 2)
    {
        return "Vital"
    }
    else if(section == 3)
    {
        return "Immunization"
    }
    return ""
}
```

Now for each section i want to add the same image and i have done this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(5,10,15,15))  // create button
    button.tag = section
    button.center = CGPointMake(320.0, 480.0)
    // the button is image - set image
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icoCheckCircle"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    let tapOnCardCell: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HHLabTestExaminationViewController.handleTapOnSectionImage(_:)))
    button.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnCardCell)

    return button
}
```

The problem is **Section title disappears as i keep the button**

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this two delegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: "your expected headerview height")

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(5,10,15,15))  // create button
    button.tag = section
    button.center = headerView.center
    headerView.addSubview(button)
    // the button is image - set image
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icoCheckCircle"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    let tapOnCardCell: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HHLabTestExaminationViewController.handleTapOnSectionImage(_:)))
button.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnCardCell)

    return headerView
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return  "your expected header"
}
```

Comment: what is the reason for disappearance of title..??

Comment: if you use  tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?  this delegate, it will call last. so title will disappear.

Comment: please use answered two delegates